# IdentityServer4 - Use different user stores based on client_id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am creating an identity service using IdentityServer4 and AspNetCore.Identity. The service will serve multiple websites which need to have separate users. As such I was thinking the simplest way to keep users separate is to have separate user collections in my database (in my case MongoDb), and simply use a different one based on the `client_id`.

I am registering my `IUserRepository` like so:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository>(x => new UserRepository(mongoClient));
```

I was thinking the easiest way to achieve what I want is to handle it at the DI level, so I have come up with so far is to change this to:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserRepository>(x => GetUserRepo(x, mongoClient));
```

Where `GetUserRepo` is a method that reads the `client_id` out of the request and returns a repository for the correct user collection.

This does seem to work but my issue is how "hacky" the implementation of `GetUserRepo` has to be:

1. I have to check if the request url is `/connect/token` and if it is, manually read the request body to find the `client_id`
2. If the user is passing a Bearer token (my identity service also includes a management API for creating users etc) then I have to manually decode the token and find the `client_id` claim

Really I am just wondering if there is a nicer way to do this (anything provided by IdentityServer4?) and also if this is "ok" to do at all?

The only thing I have found that could maybe help is [IIdentityServerInteractionService.GetAuthorizationContextAsync](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/interactionservice.html#refinteractionservice) however this requires a `returnUrl` which I don't have as I am using client credentials or resource owner password credentials methods to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically an answer but as it might help put others on the right track:

After thinking more carefully about our scenario I realised it wasn't really necessary to do what I was trying to do. Instead each website will simply use `AspNetCore.Identity` to handle their own users (with their own data stores) and I am just using `IdentityServer` to secure my API and set each website up as a client.